# WPF, XML Datagrid Binding

Tags: xml, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have an XML file  something like below. I plan to bind the contents of the XML file to a Datagrid in WPF.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProductData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<PurchaseOrderLine>
    <ProductItem>
        <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>  
    </ProductItem>
</PurchaseOrderLine>
```

So I develop two simple classes for PurchaseOrderLine and ProductItem as below

```
class PurchaseOrderLine {
    public ProductItem productItem { get; set; }}

class ProductItem{
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }}
```

After that when I tried to access it in xaml something like below, I couldn't get LineNumber details, why is that? Am I missing any? Actually please let me know how to access child elements in xml?

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements[PurchaseOrderLine]}" Height="214" Width="657">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Line Number" Binding="{Binding Path = Element[ProductItem.LineNumber].Value}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

I am loading the xml file dynamically

```
        var productList = XElement.Load(FileName);
        this.dataGrid.DataContext = productList;
```

Comment: Did you try lowercase "ProductItem" in your second binding (ie. "productItem")? XAML is case-sensitive to my recollection. Do you get any System.Data exceptions in the output window?

Comment: @  LordTakkera, Is it the right way to access the elements like ProductItem.LineNumber. Because I tried with productItem.LineNumber too. It is not working

Comment: Normally that's what you would do (with the lowercase given your property name). I'm not sure why it would be any different reading off of a XML document. Have you tried removing the "Element" from the second binding? If the object is already the data context, it might not be an XElement anymore and thus not need this piece. System.Data exceptions could help guide you here.

Comment: @ LordTakkera Wondering no exception at all. Is there any other way to bind xml files?

Comment: You could alwasy deserialize (instead of using XElement). If that solution is acceptable to you I could post a sample as an answer.

Comment: @LordTakkera You are welcome :-). Please give me a detail answer

Comment: Let me know what you think. BTW, I'm pretty sure there is a way to do this with XDocs, but I am just not familiar enough with it to know how. I do know serialization though :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't have a lot of experience with XElement, but you *could* use a serializer. There are two available in .NET, XMLSerializer, and DataContractSerializer (both are XML based). I usually use DataContractSerializer, though the principle is the same in the other.

To use it, first mark your data classes as DataContracts:

```
[DataContract]
public class PurchaseOrderLine {
    [DataMember]
    public ProductItem productItem { get; set; }}

[DataContract]
public class ProductItem{
    [DataMember]
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }}
```

Then, just use the serializer to populate your list:

```
using FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName,
            FileMode.Open))
{
    DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<PurchasOrderLine>));

    List<PurchasOrderLine> productList=
                (List<PurchasOrderLine>)ser.ReadObject(fs);

    this.dataGrid.DataContext = productList;
}
```

Then you bind like they were just regular objects:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PurchaseOrderLine}" Height="214" Width="657">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Line Number" Binding="{Binding Path=productItem.LineNumber.Value}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Note that I would bind the DataGrid's itemsource to "productList" (exposed as a public property of the VM) instead of your DataContext set, so if this code doesn't work, you might try that.

Good luck, and let me know if I can correct or clarify anything!